# Unable to satisfy the following requirements, AFNetworking dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoapods, afnetworking-3

I am using cocoapods to import AFNetworking,
I get the following error after I try `pod install`

> [!] Unable to satisfy the following requirements:
>
> - `AFNetworking (~> 3.0)` required by `Podfile`
>
> Specs satisfying the `AFNetworking (~> 3.0)` dependency were found,
>   but they required a higher minimum deployment target.

I am using pod version 0.39.0 and the project Deployment Target is 8.0

Here is my Podfile content:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

platform :ios, ‘8.0’

pod 'AFNetworking’,’~>3.0’
```

Which is same as the requested by AFNetworking from 
https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking

May I have any idea about the error?

Comment: is that your entire `Podfile`?

Comment: No, There are a quiet long Podfile, so i only write the part of it.

Comment: The rest of them just the others library which the app required

Comment: I found out the error is due to i also pod 'AFNetwortActivityLogger'

Comment: But how to due with it?  My project also required 'AFNetwortActivityLogger'

Comment: Exact the same problem here, tried out iOS version 8.0, 8.2, 9.0 all of them didn't work, still the same problem.